# What is the force of gravity on two particles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

> Suppose that I have a system of two particles. They have the same mass $m$. At the origin O is something with a very large mass $M$ which is attracting the two particles. The first particle has distance 1 to O. The second particle has distance 2 to O. Now, what is the total gravitational force on the system?

If I first calculate the two forces separately, I see that the force on particle 1 is $\frac{C}{1^2}$, where $C=GMm$ is a constant. The force on particle 2 is $\frac{C}{2^2}$. Therefore, the total force is $\frac54 C$.

However, we could also calculate the force on the entire system using the center of mass. The center of mass is at distance $\frac32$ from $O$. The total mass of the system is $2m$. Therefore, the total force is $\frac{2C}{(\frac32)^2}=\frac89 C$.

So is the total force equal to $\frac54 C$ or $\frac89 C$?

Update: the origin and the two particles are on a straight line. Also, to view the two particles as one ‘system’, we can say that the two particles are attached to the ends of a massless rope with a length larger than 1. Finally, the force between the particles is negligible.

Comment: *"total gravitational force on the system"* What does that even mean? You should calculate the gravitational forces between each pair of objects.

Comment: What should I clarify for the question to reopen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating the force due to gravity, you can replace a system of objects with a single object at the system's centre of mass *in a uniform gravitational field*. However, in this case the gravitational field is not uniform. In other words, the [centre of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_of_gravity_in_non-uniform_fields)  of the system of two particles does *not* coincide with their centre of mass.

Comment: The center of gravity of the system would be $\left(x_1 m_1  g(x_1) + x_2 m_2 g(x_2)\right)/\left(m_1 g(x_1) + m_2 g(x_2)\right) = \left(1 \frac{1}{1^2} + 2 \frac{1}{2^2}\right)/\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2}\right) = \frac{6}{5}$. And the force of gravity on an object of mass $2m$ located there would be $\frac{25}{18}C$. But I'm not sure what that tells you.  I think the only answer is just the net (external) gravitational force on the system of smaller masses: $\frac{5}{4}C$.

Comment: @Ben H, I think that your formula for the center of gravity is incorrect, because it should give $\frac54C$ for the total force

Comment: @Riemann I'm happy to adjust or delete. Can you explain what you mean?  In the case of three masses along a line, I was applying the equation for "parallel fields" found at the wikipedia page for [center of gravity in nonuniform fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_of_gravity_in_non-uniform_fields), i.e., the weighted sum of weights.

Comment: @BenH Since the distance between the objects has the same order of magnitude as their distance from the primary, the gravitational field between them is not even approximately parallel.

Comment: @gandalf61 The gravitational field vectors of M along a line through M are certainly parallel, no? I assumed all masses were along a line (otherwise Riemann's statement of center of mass distance being 3/2 would not have made sense).

Comment: I am not sure whether the weights in the formula of Wikipedia are equal to the gravitational force on the particles